# Duplicate values and overlapping selectAll's in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a d3.js noob, I just started learning for a quick exercise.
I'm appending different texts with different patterns so I'm using different functions using the `selectAll("text")` statement.

But there was an issue with this. If I append 3 labels and then tried to append 4 more, only the 4th would've been applied. That's because the selectAll would go through the ones that have already been inserted. Googling this issue I learned the solution was to use `.data(data, function(d){ return d; })` and the new elements would've been added properly. So far all my issues have been solved.

The problem arrises now that I need to append the values "40" and "60" twice in two different contexts but the duplicate values are ignored.
Again I googled for a solution and came up to this post - [Complex data object with duplicate 'values' = missing chart bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112939/complex-data-object-with-duplicate-values-missing-chart-bars) It says the solution is to remove the same line I mentioned before or use a different value, but in my case I'm dealing with a plain array of numbers. And removing the line that includes previous elements doesn't help because the next elements won't be appended.

EDIT: There is a github issue discussing this [Clarify behavior for selection.data in re. to duplicate keys. #997](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/997#ref-commit-60f3eb9) - I didn't find it clarifying in any way. Perhaps you'll make better sense of it than I did...

EDIT 2: here's a [jsFiddle explaining the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/thaenor/qtfvs1yh/2/)

Comment: Hi. Has you some jsfiddle to test it?

Comment: @Klaujesi the fiddle in the post I linked (http://jsfiddle.net/Alexbbrown/KM9dj/) demonstrates how the duplicates aren't shown. This forked version shows the same with already existing elements. http://jsfiddle.net/46v6e575/

Comment: Remove de function I on data .data([3,2,3], I ) > .data([3,2,3])

Comment: @Klaujesi that isn't working. the output I expect is: "3,2,3,3" d3 is ignoring repetition but I don't want that.

Comment: remove the second .enter(). The second add is not un .enter() event, instead it is an .update()

Comment: @Klaujesi does d3.js have an update method that replaces the enter() ? I honestly don't know, and I don't have time to dwelve into the documentation.

Comment: Sorry. But the bug still remains. This fix is now included in alpha 41

Comment: wait, so this is a bug from d3.js?

Comment: Yeap. Was posted on 2013. https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/997. 24 day ago Mike post this: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/commit/60f3eb9f52aa8e3807c81bf5321f8811ab315722 but the bug still remains :(

Comment: @Klaujesi I was convinced that those values were like so on porpuse to see if I could handle that error... if I use the alfa version will my code work?

Comment: Looks at this: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/  and this: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#data

Comment: I think I got it. I didn't look much into svg groups (the "g") but if I had used those I probably wouldn't have those problems with the selections. Maybe I could've used ```selectAll("somegroup")``` instead of "text" and that would have helped overlapping previous elements I've inserted. The other solution, as you stated, would've been to edit the data so it holds key/value pairs and thus avoids repetition. btw here's the finished project [link](https://github.com/thaenor/d3js-circular-experience)

Comment: wow. That's graph are so gorgeous. Well done. Nice work, thanks for share

Comment: thanks @Klaujesi I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due this is a well documented bug with no fix, you can tweak your data, adding an index to prevent wrong selection on duplicate keys:

```
[{index:1, value:3},
 {index:2, value:2},
 {index:3, value:3}]
```

and referencing as: d.index and d.value:

```
d3.select(".I997").selectAll("p")
            .data([{index:1, value:3},{index:2, value:2},{index:3, value:3}])
      .enter()
      .append("p")
      .text(function (d) {return d.value})

d3.selectAll("p")
      .data([{index:4, value:3}])
      .append ("p")
      .text(function (d) {return d.value})
```

or you can use this:

```
var ps = d3.select("body").selectAll('div')
  .data([3, 2, 3])
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .text(String);

d3.selectAll('div')
  .data([3])
  .append('div')
  .text(String);
```

this works as you expect

Here the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/5rxadq4q/

https://jsfiddle.net/v0n8971q/1/

Comment: I've recreated the fiddle because I forgot to mention one thing. In my actual project I'm appending elements to a canvas, not to html tags. So when it came to the actual bit of buggy code there was already inserted text elements which were included by the selectAll. I have made those changes in the fiddle and it seems fine so long as I manipulate data as you've said. https://jsfiddle.net/thaenor/xcz0mpoo/2/

Comment: Actually I'll need to edit my last comment. I do still have some issues. In my app I'm appeding text labels with different things. Some simply have text and others are numbers from various sources. Because there's all these different "breeds" of text using ```canvas.selectAll("text").data(nArray, function(d){return d.index;})``` won't work because the first text elements in the canvas don't have a ```.index``` property